# ArgumentError (Account SID and auth token are required):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I am getting the following error when I input a phone number into a form field

> ArgumentError in Apps::TextyController#send_text
>
> Account SID and auth token are required

But I have the Auth token and the Account SID in the code.

```html
module Messenger

  def send_sms(number)
    acct_sid = ENV['AC0b06exxxxxxxxxxxxx']
    auth_token = ENV['68ce616xxxxxxxxxxx']

     @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new acct_sid, auth_token

    from = '+6466817345'

    message = @client.account.messages.create(
        :from => from,
        :to => '+1'+number,
        :body => 'accept my application'
        )
  end

end
```

I am using an older Ruby -v 2.2.0 and Rails 4.

This is texty_controller.rb

```html
class Apps::TextyController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @phone = Phone.new
  end

  def send_text
    @phone = Phone.new(phone_params)
    @phone.send_sms(@phone.clean_number)
    @phone.save
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def phone_params
    params.require(:phone).permit(:number)
  end

end
```

[which is a clone from the following website](https://github.com/lowellmower/vlog)

Answer (score 2):

How have you stored the SID and Auth Token as environment variables? The norm is to save them in an application.yml file and name them something like
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN = 'AUSHXU******'
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID = 'SUHXB823*****'

and then call them using ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'].

Have you tried calling your environment variables in the console? If you get nil that means that you are not accessing them correctly and thus your acct_sid and auth_token local variables will be nil.

Comment: I believe I have not store them in an application.yml file. Should I create one? and if so in what folder should it go? Also can you tell me how to call environment variables in the console? thanks

Comment: if you run the command "rails c" in your terminal you can then simply write ENV['AC0b06exxxxxxxxxxxxx'] as you have done in your code. If this returns your Twilio Account SID then it is correct, if it returns nil it means that it is not finding this environment variable.

Comment: You can create the application.yml in the config folder of your Rails app. Then using the standard YAML notation you can store your variables (e.g. TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN: '************'). Then try calling ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'] in the console and your token should be returned

Comment: So when I runned the rails console ENV['AC0b06exxxxxxxxxxxxx']  it returned nil. After creating the application.yml and running ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'] it returned the token however when I run the server I still get the same error.

Comment: also when I runned the ```rails server``` I get the following warnings.

Comment: WARNING: Skipping key "TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN". Already set in ENV. WARNING: Skipping key "TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID". Already set in ENV.

Comment: hmm, that means that the environment variables are already being set somewhere else. Can you do a search all in your text editor (Sublime Text is ctrl + shift + f) for TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN to see if it already being set somewhere else?

Comment: Also, did you change the code in your Messenger module to use ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN'] and ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by doing the following steps.

1) I modified the messenger.rb file by saving the acct_sid and auth_token the following way:

`acct_sid = 'AC0b06exxxxxxxxxxxxx'`

`auth_token = '68ce616xxxxxxxxxxx`

2) then after saving the file I went on terminal and export the enviroment variables from there the following way:

`export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN=AC0b06exxxxxxxxxxxxx`

`export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID=68ce616xxxxxxxxxxx`

3) In step three I go to the messenger.rb file and modified the acct_sid and auth_token the following way.

`acct_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']`

`auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']`

Make sure that your using TWILIO live credentials. Test credentials are limited to [three resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/test-credentials#supported-resources).